# Is there a quicker way to do this in Numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, array-broadcasting

I want to generate a 3D matrix in numpy. The code is:

```
mean_value = np.array([1, 2, 3], dtype=np.float32)
h, w = 5, 5
b = np.ones((h, w, 1), dtype=np.float32) * np.reshape(mean_value, [1, 1, 3])
print(b.shape)  # (5, 5, 3)
```

Is there any quicker way for generating `b`? Thanks.

Comment: quicker in what sense? `np.array([[[1, 2, 3]*h]*w])` is a lot less code and I suspect faster, because the python list is just populated with references to the same object.

Comment: @JoshuaF thank you for your comment! I'm not sure if my code is efficient. So I'm asking for help on improving efficiency. Your solution is very brilliant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For efficiency (memory, performance), simply `broadcast` with [`np.broadcast_to`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_to.html) for a view output -

```
np.broadcast_to(mean_value,(h,w,)+mean_value.shape)
```

Being a view, it has no memory overhead and hence, virtually free on runtime.

Let's verify the performance part -

```
In [45]: mean_value = np.array([1, 2, 3], dtype=np.float32)
    ...: h, w = 5, 5

In [46]: %timeit np.broadcast_to(mean_value,(h,w,)+mean_value.shape)
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.21 µs per loop

In [47]: mean_value = np.random.rand(10000)
    ...: h, w = 5000, 5000

In [48]: %timeit np.broadcast_to(mean_value,(h,w,)+mean_value.shape)
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.22 µs per loop
```

And memory part (being a view) -

```
In [49]: np.shares_memory(mean_value,np.broadcast_to(mean_value,(h,w,)+mean_value.shape))
Out[49]: True
```